# Asp.Net Web Api - Passing String[] values from swagger to Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am calling an external API from my Asp.Net Web Api.. I am testing it using swagger and from swagger i am passing array of DepartmentCodes as `["IT","HR"]` , when i am testing it using swagger the API is failing because of the DepartmenCodes array.

I am posting only partial code here as the issue is only with the string[] values being passed from swagger.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers([FromUri] GetUserRequest getUserRequest)
{
   UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
   userRequest.DepartmentCodes = getUserRequest.DepartmentCodes;
   using (var Client = new HttpClient())
   {
     //code to call external api
   }
}

Public Class UserRequest
{
  Public string[] DepartmentCodes {get;set;}
}

Public Class GetUserRequest
{
  Public string[] DepartmentCodes {get;set;}
}
```

When i am hardcoding the DepartmentCodes array in the code, the API is working as expected and i am getting the result.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers([FromUri] GetUserRequest getUserRequest)
{
   UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
   userRequest.DepartmentCodes = new string[] {"IT", "HR"};
   //userRequest.DepartmentCodes = getUserRequest.DepartmentCodes;
   using (var Client = new HttpClient())
   {
     //code to call external api
   }
}
```

In order for the API to work with swagger, do we have to make any change in the code or do i need to change the way i am passing string array from swagger.. currently from swagger i am passing the string array as ["IT, HR"]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, It worked when i tried  posting the string array values from swagger in the below way

```
IT
HR
```

There shouldn't be any double quotes, commas or any other special characters...